# Parsing (3rd) Nested JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing, object

I am trying to parse following JSON with PHP but at the very last level (`"bank"`) having some issues, following is the information:

JSON:

```
{
    "loan": {
        "fu": "1046",
        "vb": "84",
        "loan_type": "1",
        "type_cocg": "14",
        "meeting_place": "PLACE",
        "meeting_date": "2019-05-29",
        "creation_date": "2019-05-29 12:49:53",
        "user_id": "1001-1556",
        "member": [{
            "mem_id": "1",
            "name": "FIRST MEMBER",
            "parentage": "PARENTAGE",
            "cnic": "3393399393393",
            "gender": "1",
            "dob": "1994-05-29",
            "marital_status": "1",
            "spouse_name": "SPOUSE",
            "spouse_cnic": "9939439939393",
            "pres_address": "PRES ADDRESS",
            "perma_address": "PERMA ADDRESS",
            "mother_name": "MOTHER NAME",
            "cell": "94494944949",
            "loan_amount": "30000",
            "network": "1",
            "sim_ownership": "2",
            "co_status": "3",
            "occupation_category": "2",
            "agri_occ": "null",
            "nonagri_occ": "3",
            "education": "1",
            "disability": "2",
            "religion": "6",
            "head": "2",
            "purpose": "2",
            "repayment_mode": "null",
            "duration": "4",
            "purpose_ent": "null",
            "purpose_agri": "null",
            "area_unit": "2",
            "agri_investment": "",
            "agri_expense": "",
            "purpose_livestock": "3",
            "loan_id_mem": "1",
            "monthly_income": "15000",
            "monthly_expense": "2000",
            "monthly_saving": "13000",
            "yearly_saving": "156000",
            "male": "2",
            "female": "2",
            "children": "2",
            "cow": "2",
            "buffalo": "2",
            "goat": "2",
            "sheep": "2",
            "agri_area_unit": "1",
            "land_own": "3",
            "land_lease": "3",
            "house_own": "3",
            "house_rent": "3",
            "caste": "CASTE",
            "active_loan": "1",
            "bank": [{
                "id": "1",
                "loan_id": "1",
                "loan_mem_id": "1",
                "bank_id": "1",
                "bank_loan": "",
                "bank_remaining": "2000",
                "purpose": "1",
                "purpose_agri": "16",
                "purpose_livestock": "null",
                "purpose_ent": "null"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "loan_id": "1",
                "loan_mem_id": "1",
                "bank_id": "6",
                "bank_loan": "",
                "bank_remaining": "500",
                "purpose": "3",
                "purpose_agri": "16",
                "purpose_livestock": "null",
                "purpose_ent": "14"
            }]
        }, {
            "mem_id": "2",
            "name": "SECOND MEMBER",
            "parentage": "PARENTAGE",
            "cnic": "3939939393399",
            "gender": "1",
            "dob": "1994-05-29",
            "marital_status": "1",
            "spouse_name": "SPOUSE",
            "spouse_cnic": "4949949494999",
            "pres_address": "ADDRESS",
            "perma_address": "ADDRESS",
            "mother_name": "MOTHER",
            "cell": "49494949494",
            "loan_amount": "20000",
            "network": "1",
            "sim_ownership": "2",
            "co_status": "2",
            "occupation_category": "2",
            "agri_occ": "null",
            "nonagri_occ": "2",
            "education": "1",
            "disability": "1",
            "religion": "1",
            "head": "1",
            "purpose": "1",
            "repayment_mode": "null",
            "duration": "3",
            "purpose_ent": "null",
            "purpose_agri": "16",
            "area_unit": "1",
            "agri_investment": "1500",
            "agri_expense": "2000",
            "purpose_livestock": "3",
            "loan_id_mem": "1",
            "monthly_income": "15000",
            "monthly_expense": "200",
            "monthly_saving": "14800",
            "yearly_saving": "177600",
            "male": "0",
            "female": "0",
            "children": "2",
            "cow": "2",
            "buffalo": "2",
            "goat": "2",
            "sheep": "2",
            "agri_area_unit": "1",
            "land_own": "3",
            "land_lease": "3",
            "house_own": "3",
            "house_rent": "2",
            "caste": "CASTE 2",
            "active_loan": "1",
            "bank": [{
                "id": "3",
                "loan_id": "1",
                "loan_mem_id": "2",
                "bank_id": "6",
                "bank_loan": "",
                "bank_remaining": "300",
                "purpose": "1",
                "purpose_agri": "43",
                "purpose_livestock": "null",
                "purpose_ent": "null"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

PHP code:

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$json['loan']['fu']; // This works !

foreach($json['loan']['member'] as $item) {
   $name = $item['name']; // This works !
   foreach($json['loan']['member']['bank'] as $bank_item) { // THIS DOES NOT WORKS!

   }
}
```

The last `foreach` loop gives out en error saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: bank

Are there any clues as to what might be causing the issue, or is there some improved way of parsing the same JSON, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json parsing is fine. your accessing is missing index.

As the "bank" is inside an array of "member" you should access as `$json['loan']['member'][0]['bank']` (the 0 is hard coded - you can switch for 1 also).

If you use for then you should do:

```
foreach($json['loan']['member'] as $item) {  
   $name = $item['name']; // This works !
   foreach($item['bank'] as $bank_item) { // use $item

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only a single `foreach()` and get the bank element value. If you further need to loop on bank element then you can use another `foreach()`

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);
foreach($json['loan']['member'] as $item) {
  print_r($item['bank']);
  foreach($item['bank'] as $bank_item) { 
      echo $bank_item;
   }
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/qB8mV

Comment: I tried this, it prints the array (banks) just fine with print_r, however to individually retrieve each variable inside the banks array, using $json['loan']['member'][0]['bank'] might be the better way (replacing 0 with the looping index value), Thanks nonetheless for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You have missed that member is also multidimensional array

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);
    /*
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
    echo "</pre>";*/
    foreach($json['loan']['member'] as $item => $value) {

       $name = $value['name']; // This works !

       foreach($json['loan']['member'][$item]['bank'] as $bank_item) { // THIS DOES NOT WORKS!

            print_r($bank_item);
       }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk_recursive()` function also

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$i=0;
foreach($json['loan']['member'] as $item) { 
 array_walk_recursive($json['loan']['member'][$i]['bank'], function($value,$key) {
        echo  $key.' :'.$value ." \n";
    });
 $i++;    
}
```

DEMO : https://3v4l.org/KDR6V